Display the selected optional dependencies package in setup.py
When I execute pip install my_package[option_dependencies] I want to detect the value of option_dependencies provided in setup.py file
In pyproject.toml file
test1 = []
test2 = []
test3 = []

and for example when I execute
pip install my_package["test1"]

I could print or check the valur "test1" in setup.py

I don't believe you can get the information as pip doesn't pass it to setup.py. It collects the list of requirements and installs it itself one by one without notifying setuptools.

Also printing from setup.py is disabled under pip, it redirects stdin/stdout/stderr and takes the screen to itself.

The primary issue I am facing is the need to execute a specific Python function within setup.py when a flag, argument, or option is provided during the execution of pip install my_package. However, pip options such as --global-option, --build-option, and --config-settings are tied to specific versions of pip. Since my_package supports Python versions 3.9 through 3.12, it is not feasible to rely on any one specific pip version, as the package should be compatible with a range of pip versions rather than a particular one.

Passing options to setup.py via environment variable(s) is perhaps the most universal way. Environment variables pass through (almost) any layers of processes, they do not depend on pip versions.
